# Handling signals and don't turn off the server

Tags: c, sockets, signals

I want to handle some signals. If I received a sigalarm or sigpipe I want simply to disconnect the current client and wait for a new client. For other signals, I disconnet the client and close the server. Do you think that the following code can be valid, both from a practical and a theoretical point of view?

```
sigset_t set;
struct sigaction sign, signAlrm, sigPipe;
char *usr;
void chiusuraSig(){
    close(serv_sock_acc);
    close(serv_sock);
    free(usr);
    exit(1);
}

void gestioneSigPipe(){
    alarm(RESET);
    close(serv_sock_acc);
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sigPipe, NULL);
    free(usr);
    work(); //where I accept the client
}

void chiusuraSigAlrm(){
    close(serv_sock_acc);
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &signAlrm, NULL);
    free(usr);
    work(); //where I accept client
}

void work(){ 
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);  //I can be at this point of code after an handling of a sigalarm or sigpipe, so this sigprocmask unblock is necessary, because when I handle a signal and I'm in the handling function, other signals are blocked.
    //other inscructions and accept to wait for a new client...
}
int main(){
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGHUP);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGQUIT);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGSEGV);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGALRM);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGPIPE);

    sign.sa_sigaction = chiusuraSig;
    sign.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sign.sa_mask = set;
    signAlrm.sa_sigaction = chiusuraSigAlrm;
    signAlrm.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    signAlrm.sa_mask = set;
    sigPipe.sa_sigaction = gestioneSigPipe;
    sigPipe.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigPipe.sa_mask = set;
    sigaction(SIGHUP, &sign, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sign, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &sign, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sign, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &signAlrm, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sigPipe, NULL);

    //bind+listen etc.
    work();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing while executing this code?

Comment: @Shwetha it has happened once that I got a "double free error", from what I remember because I immediately closed the terminal. I don't seem able to replicate it once again to paste here the exact code of the error. I've done many try, but everything seems fine, though I had that error which is worrying me :/
The assumption I made about the sigprocmask is right?

Comment: I made it! I'm receiving this code *** Error in `./server': double free or corruption (top): 0x085cd008 ***
Aborted (core dumped). I think that it has to do with the way I'm handling signals. I receive this code when I handle two sigpipe or sigalarm in row.

Comment: You can use a debugger like "Valgrind", to check these memory related issues. Also, try to compile with a -g option which can help you to locate the exact location of the error.

Comment: @Shwetha I think that I understood what happened. I could receive a sigalarm before that usr receives a malloc in the code. If the first time I malloc it, and then I receive a signal, free(usr) is executed. Then I receive a new sigalarm before than a new malloc is done, and this causes free(usr) to close the program. It has sense? Regarding the singals handling, do you think that it has done correctly?

Comment: `free()` is NOT safe to call from a signal handler, since the signal could be delivered in the middle of another call to `free()` elsewhere.  The list of functions which are safe to call from signal handlers is documented in [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) in the "Async-signal-safe functions" section.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield mm thanks for your help. In my code, the users log in and the server memorize it in a global variable "usr" used in some functions. usr is malloc and initialized in the work() function. If the current client disconnect, I need to free the memory of the usr variable so that a new user can login. Do you think that it could be a better solution do a malloc of usr at the beginning of the main(), and usr memset 0 at the beginning of the work()?

Comment: Why are you calling `work()` in your handlers???  You are in an "interrupt" context, which means the call to `work()` would be in interrupt context... I'm pretty sure that's not what you want to do.

Comment: @TonyB it's only for SigAlarm and SigPipe. I've sigalarm only after a read call on the socket, and I reset the alarm after the read call has been completed. So, if an alarm is raised, this means the the client hasn't done his work in time and must be disconnected, then the server can wait for a new client. Regarding Sigpipe, if the server can't write on a client-socket, it closes that socket and waits for a new client to connect, that's why it goes to work(). Is this wrong? I don't want the server to be closed only because the client doesn't do his work :/

Comment: I understand the need to do something at both of those times, but you are in an signal handling context... if you simply return, you will leave the signal handling context, and return in your code to where you were when hit with the signal.... i.e. a normal context.

Comment: @TonyB mm maybe that I haven't been clear with how my code works. I don't return where I was after a signal, but I do a relevant action (disconnect the client) and then I go to the point of the code where I wait for a new client. Not sure how this can be done if not in this way. What's your suggestion? Besides of this, regarding the sigset, sigaction and sigprocmask, do you think that I've implemented them correctly?

Comment: @daimpa I have insufficient space to describe the concept of an interrupt context, but here is a snip from Linux's "man 7 signal"    'Async-signal-safe functions:  signal  handler  function  must be very careful, since processing elsewhere may be interrupted at some arbitrary point in the execution of the program.  POSIX has the concept of "safe function".  If a  signal interrupts the execution of an unsafe function, and handler calls an unsafe function, then the behavior of the program is undefined.`

Comment: @daimpa The 'man 7 signal` goes on to list the function that are "safe" to call.  If your handler simply returns, you are no longer under that constraint.  You might also look at the following link for background: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Defining-Handlers.html#Defining-Handlers